Regarding gravitational interaction between two quantum particles
If there is a particle antiparticle pair kept at close distances with each other, and at rest, will they experience gravitational attraction through the exchange of gravitons and gain velocity towards each other resulting in their collision and the production of a gamma photon through pair annhilation? If so, how can we prove it?

There is no accepted theory of quantum gravity, and other interactions would likely be overwhelmingly more significant than gravity.

If they are anti-particles of one another, they would interact through their opposite charges much more dominantly than through gravitational interaction.

@paul230_x They could be a neutrino and antineutrino, both of which are chargeless.

"kept at close distances with each other" -- you have to be careful here because of the uncertainty principle. "Kept at small distances" implies both control over position and momentum. When you're dealing with relativistic particle physics, it's usually very hard to localize particles. This ties into @Ghoster's point because there might not be a semiclassical limit for the question you are asking where you can get away with classical gravity.
